# Prevent system from going to sleep/suspend - how Xviewer/VLC do it

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, suspend

When `Xviewer` or `VLC` are in full-screen mode on Linux Mint, my laptop does not go to sleep. Some other apps, e.g. `mpv` in full screen, do not prevent sleep.

There is no options in `Xviewer` GUI on keep awake status.

How does `Xviewer` do prevention and how to turn in off?

How to turn-on sleep prevention for apps where I consider this behavior beneficial, like `Transmission` for example?

Comment: What is the Desktop Environment?

Comment: @Yurij Goncharuk, Linux Mint 18.3, Cinnamon

Comment: I describe my discover in details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Linux applications inhibit suspend through a [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) call to [`org.gnome.SessionManager.Inhibit`](https://people.gnome.org/%7Emccann/gnome-session/docs/gnome-session.html#org.gnome.SessionManager.Inhibit)

### Contrasting *inhibit* vs. *prevent*

Note that *inhibit* is different than *prevent*. *Inhibiting* a screensaver, screen lock, or suspend only prevents the action from occurring when the computer is idle, not when it is manually activated by the user or another program.

### How specific applications inhibit suspend

#### Transmission

Transmission has a checkbox for inhibiting sleep in: `Preferences`-> `Desktop` tab -> `Inhibit hibernation when torrents are active`.

I downloaded the source code of Transmission and saw that it calls a D-Bus method (`org.gnome.SessionManager.Inhibit`) to the Cinnamon D-Bus session.

#### Firefox

I used [dbus-monitor](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html) to discover what Firefox does when a video is playing. When the video starts to play, then Firefox send two calls:

```
$ dbus-monitor
. . .
# disable screensaver
method call time=1523976795.844938 sender=:1.104 ->
destination=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver serial=9 path=/ScreenSaver;
interface=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver; member=Inhibit
  string "firefox"
  string "video-playing"
# disable sleeping
method call time=1523976795.893407 sender=:1.21 -> destination=:1.3
serial=61 path=/org/gnome/SessionManager;
interface=org.gnome.SessionManager; member=Inhibit
  string "firefox"
  uint32 0
  string "video-playing"
  uint32 8
. . .
```

After calling the last method, the following inhibitor was created:

```
$ dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply
--dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager
org.gnome.SessionManager.GetInhibitors
method return time=1523969881.311742 sender=:1.3 -> destination=:1.188
serial=491 reply_serial=2
  array [
     object path "/org/gnome/SessionManager/Inhibitor6"
  ]
```

When the video has been stopped, then inhibitor is being removed:

```
$ dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply
--dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager
org.gnome.SessionManager.GetInhibitors
method return time=1523969881.311742 sender=:1.3 -> destination=:1.188
serial=493 reply_serial=2
  array [
  ]
```

#### VLC

VLC inhibits sleep/suspend in the same way as Firefox:

```
$ dbus-monitor
. . .
method call time=1523977809.526716 sender=:1.8017 ->
destination=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver serial=3 path=/ScreenSaver;
interface=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver; member=Inhibit
  string "vlc"
  string "Playing some media."
method call time=1523977809.527152 sender=:1.21 -> destination=:1.3
serial=91 path=/org/gnome/SessionManager;
interface=org.gnome.SessionManager; member=Inhibit
  string "vlc"
  uint32 0
  string "Playing some media."
  uint32 8
. . .

$ dbus-send --session --type=method_call --print-reply
--dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager
org.gnome.SessionManager.GetInhibitors
method return time=1523977813.424421 sender=:1.3 ->
destination=:1.8018 serial=85789 reply_serial=2
  array [
     object path "/org/gnome/SessionManager/Inhibitor7750"
  ]
```

#### Xviewer

When you play a slideshow, Xviewer calls a D-Bus method similar to the above programs.

### How to manually inhibit suspend

There are two popular applets exists for inhibiting sleep/suspend: **[Caffeine](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/59)** and **Inhibit Applet** (built-in [Cinnamon applet](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/59): Right Click on Bottom Panel -> `Add Applets to Panel` -> `Inhibit Applet`. But these applets manually turn on and off inhibit suspend functionality, rather than automatically turning it on and off when certain applications are running.

Comment: And if there is no gnoem manager, where do I send the dbug msg to?

Comment: You need to discover the method of your desktop environment which is exists on the **Session Bus**. There are many tools (cli or gui) can be useful for this: `qdbusviewer`, `dbus-monitor`, `dbusexplorerer` ... This article about  https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10455 (Control Your Linux Desktop with D-Bus) can be helpful in your task.

Comment: This does not prevent sleep.

Comment: There is also this Python program https://github.com/gsauthof/utility/blob/69d569789e62c4a774916235bf57e0c3691cd5b9/inhibit.py which sends the D-Bus method call org.gnome.SessionManager.Inhibit (successfully tested) and probably https://man.archlinux.org/man/extra/gnome-session/gnome-session-inhibit.1.en (not tested)

Answer (score 2):

`systemd-inhibit --what=idle mpv` will inhibit idle timeout.

You can also inhibit sleep (including via lid switch etc) or shutdown (including via power button). See [man systemd-inhibit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-inhibit.html). This command has been available in systemd since 2012.