# How to tell gnome-session(3), or gnome-screensaver, that there's been activity?

Tags: gnome3, screen-lock

Under some circumstances I don't want my screen to lock. (Typically: I'm stepping away from the desk, while a computation is running, but I won't leave the room and still have an eye on it why it's active; sometimes, I'll add more tasks to a queue, so that it's not "done when it's done")

Is there a mechanism to tell GNOME session or ~ screensaver not to lock? I was expecting there to be a clever DBUS API for that, but GNOME's documentation seems to depend on the private homedir of someone who's since deleted it: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/SessionManagement/GnomeSession#D-Bus_API links to the 404 [https://www.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-session/docs/gnome-session.html](https://www.gnome.org/%7Emccann/gnome-session/docs/gnome-session.html).

Even better: is there a Freedesktop standardized API for this? I mostly work on Cinnamon-session with an awesome WM, but this problem I encounter mostly on machines where I've only got access to a Gnome session; however, if there's a one-size-fits-all solution, I'd greatly prefer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least under X, you can use [`xdg-screensaver`](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-screensaver.html) to inhibit a compliant screensaver as long as a given window exists:

```
xdg-screensaver suspend <window-id>
```

There is [a Freedesktop D-Bus interface for screensavers](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/idle-inhibit-spec/0.1/re01.html), which you would invoke using something like

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver --type=method_call --print-reply \
          /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.Inhibit \
          string:"myapplication" string:"displaying long computations"
```

but that doesn’t work from `dbus-send` since it’s tied to the caller — calling it from a long-running Python script should do the trick.

(`--print-reply` is included because the return value is important — it’s a cookie used to uninhibit the screensaver.)

See also [Prevent system from going to sleep/suspend - how Xviewer/VLC do it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437735/86440)

Comment: yesss! This seems to be what I'm looking for!